# Python Array problems

Tags: python

I want to run a command in a python file,and then results from that command,to be inside an array so i can insert that array inside a db later.Here's my code:

```
import sqlite3
import subprocess

assetfinder = subprocess.Popen(["assetfinder -subs-only cysecor.rs | sort -u"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
assetfinder_out = assetfinder.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

domains = []
for item in assetfinder_out:
    domains.append(assetfinder_out.strip())
print(domains)

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Here is my output:

```
['autodiscover.cysecor.rs\ncpanel.cysecor.rs\ncpcalendars.cysecor.rs\ncpcontacts.cysecor.rs\ncysecor.rs\nkurs.cysecor.rs\nmail.cysecor.rs\nwebdisk.cysecor.rs\nwebmail.cysecor.rs\nwww.cysecor.rs\nwww.kurs.cysecor.rs', 'autodiscover.cysecor.rs\ncpanel.cysecor.rs\ncpcalendars.cysecor.rs\ncpcontacts.cysecor.rs\ncysecor.rs\nkurs.cysecor.rs\nmail.cysecor.rs\nwebdisk.cysecor.rs\nwebmail.cysecor.rs\nwww.cysecor.rs\nwww.kurs.cysecor.rs', 'autodiscover.cysecor.rs\ncpanel.cysecor.rs\ncpcalendars.cysecor.rs\ncpcontacts.cysecor.rs\ncysecor.rs\nkurs.cysecor.rs\nmail.cysecor.rs\nwebdisk.cysecor.rs\nwebmail.cysecor.rs\nwww.cysecor.rs\nwww.kurs.cysecor.rs', 'autodiscover.cysecor.rs\ncpanel.cysecor.rs\ncpcalendars.cysecor.rs\ncpcontacts.cysecor.rs\ncysecor.rs\nkurs.cysecor.rs\nmail.cysecor.rs\nwebdisk.cysecor.rs\nwebmail.cysecor.rs\nwww.cysecor.rs\nwww.kurs.cysecor.rs', 'autodiscover.cysecor.rs\ncpanel.cysecor.rs\ncpcalendars.cysecor.rs\ncpcontacts.cysecor.rs\ncysecor.rs\nkurs.cysecor.rs\nmail.cysecor.rs\nwebdisk.cysecor.rs\nwebmail.cysecor.rs\nwww.cysecor.rs\nwww.kurs.cysecor.rs'
```

This cloned like 100 times.I want to get every item not all items in 1 item,and then that one item cloned 100 times.Any fix??

Comment: `domains = assetfinder_out.strip().split()`…?

Answer (score 4):

`assetfinder_out` is a `str` object. You iterate over it and for every char append the whole string to `domains` list.
As far as I can see the assets are delimited by new line `\n`. So just split the string.

```
import subprocess

assetfinder = subprocess.Popen(["assetfinder -subs-only cysecor.rs | sort -u"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
assetfinder_out = assetfinder.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

domains = assetfinder_out.splitlines()
```

Comment: Yea it works fine,didnt know that assetfinder_out is a str object.However thanks mate